OpenCV feature matching for low contrast images
First time post here!
I'm having difficulty in trying to feature match with the attached images.
Generally I've been successful with other images with SIFT. The relevant code is below. You can see the parameters I passed associated with the matched image attached.
Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach... but I do need rotation invariant matching.
Looking for help or suggestions in how to proceed otherwise.
I've tried a bunch of different pre processing operations (dilate/expand, contrast, denoise, histogram correction, edges, contrast, blur, threshold....).
I was trying to filter out noise in the image and really highlight those dark areas so that SIFT had something more concrete to find.
I looked at image matching but like I mentioned, I need rotation.
Appreciate the help!
image 1:

image 2:

Here is code that can be copy pasted with the images above:
import cv2 

img_obj_raw = cv2.imread('b3KDF_01.png')
output_cropped = img_obj_raw[93:(93+185),121:(121+237)]
img_obj = output_cropped

img_scn_raw = cv2.imread('b3KDF_02.png')
output_cropped = img_scn_raw[68:(68+235),96:(96+287)]
img_scn = output_cropped

img_obj = cv2.cvtColor(img_obj, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_scn = cv2.cvtColor(img_scn, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Adaptive Histogram equalization
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=5, tileGridSize=(20, 20))
img_obj = clahe.apply(img_obj)
img_scn = clahe.apply(img_scn)

# create SIFT feature extractor
sift = cv2.SIFT_create(nfeatures = 0, nOctaveLayers = 3, contrastThreshold = 0.04, edgeThreshold = 10, sigma = 1.6)

# detect features from the image
keypoints_obj, descriptors_obj = sift.detectAndCompute(img_obj, None)
keypoints_scn, descriptors_scn = sift.detectAndCompute(img_scn, None)

# create feature matcher
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50) 
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)

matches = matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_obj, descriptors_scn, k=2)

# Apply ratio test
good_matches = []
ratio = 0.5
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < ratio*n.distance:
        good_matches.append([m])

img_obj_rawkp = cv2.drawKeypoints(img_obj, keypoints_obj, None)
img_scn_rawkp = cv2.drawKeypoints(img_scn, keypoints_scn, None)

# draw matches
img_matched = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img_obj_rawkp, keypoints_obj, img_scn_rawkp, keypoints_scn, good_matches, None, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
cv2.imshow('img_matched', img_matched)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


I don't know if this will work on your images, but see the 3rd example for the retina images for phase correlation at https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.registration.html#skimage.registration.phase_cross_correlation. You might have to remove the background around your figures and perhaps increase the contrast and/or threshold to enhance the images. Sorry, I don't have the time right now to test the idea.

Just noticed that the two images are not simply rotated and shifted. The cardboard is different between the two.

I'll tell you what I see: cardboard on the floor. three panels that all look the same, positioned in different ways. one scene differs from the other in how the panels are arranged. -- "matching" the one image to the other is impossible because the scene has changed. -- you might want to identify what you want to "match". the word is terrible. maybe you want to find instances (three instances here) of the "panel"? -- what is the goal, in your own words? you described what you're trying to do ("matching"), but not why you're doing it (the goal).

these "cardboard panel" objects have too few unique features for feature matching to even make sense. I think you'll want to reach for "machine vision" approaches or programs.

Why do you need the feature matching anyway? What are you trying to achieve?

@ChristophRackwitz thanks for helping. The intent is just to identify if a cardboard case is there or not. Each one gets picked up and removed. Underneath it is either another case (could be rotated and translated) or nothing (a piece of cardboard without the features that highlight the cardboard flaps)

@TinoD check out the reply to Chris. What do you think?

this is basically object detection. just throw AI at it. the robot won't move faster than the AI can infer. train a model to infer center points. either make it infer one point at a time, or infer a heat map and find local maxima (recipe for NMS on raster data (heatmap)). you could pay someone to annotate a bunch of pictures and/or come up with synthetic data. data augmentation on top of that should also be fairly easy.

yeah was hoping to not have to do AI. I dont know how many different models id have to train (lots of different cases in reality) and wanted to see if there was a robust way of just detecting the flaps of the flat case. to your point on machine vision, i think thats probably the path. standard pattern match/edge detect with color requirements in certain areas would be pretty easy i think for something like cognex. but no good open source libraries for this. perhaps the SIFT path would be best for non-brown cases, so use both methods. thanks brainstorming this with me @ChristophRackwitz

in one customer's warehouse, they were setting up a robot that would comb the pallet with a laser scanner to obtain a 3D surface of the goods. it would then decide what lumps in that 3D point cloud/mesh would be most likely to be bags of powder, and then go pick them with an array of suckers. -- anything that can solve the problem reliably will be more involved than "plain old 2D camera and a bit of image processing". look at what boston dynamics does with their "stretch" robot do (on youtube).
